# R conditional rowSums to replace with sums based on percentage

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, conditional-statements, rowsum

I'm looking to conditionally rowSums if those rows represent <1% of the data - and then replace the original values with the rowSums. *Bonus if the table could include the number of rows that were summed into the name column (e.g., "Other(n=2)"). This is a small part of a much larger function. See example below:

Example data:

| name | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 | Total | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 0.7029877 |
| Paul | 230 | 100 | 150 | 480 | 84.358524 |
| George | 41 | 30 | 10 | 81 | 14.235501 |
| Ringo | 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 0.7029877 |

```
# Code for example data
name <- c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo")
Year1 <- c(1, 230, 41, 2)
Year2 <- c(2, 100, 30, 1)
Year3 <- c(1, 150, 10, 1)
df <- data.frame(name, Year1, Year2, Year3)
df$Total <- rowSums(select(df,Year1:Year3))
df$Percent <- df$Total/sum(df$Total)*100
```

In the solution, John and Ringo would be combined into one 'Other' solution since both have Percent < 1.

```
# Code for example solution
name <- c("Paul", "George", "Other(n=2)")
Year1 <- c(230, 41, 3)
Year2 <- c(100, 30, 3)
Year3 <- c(150, 10, 2)
df2 <- data.frame(name, Year1, Year2, Year3)
df2$Total <- rowSums(select(df2,Year1:Year3))
df2$Percent <- df2$Total/sum(df2$Total)*100
```

Example solution:

| name | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 | Total | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 230 | 100 | 150 | 480 | 84.358524 |
| George | 41 | 30 | 10 | 81 | 14.235501 |
| Other(n=2) | 3 | 3 | 2 | 8 | 1.405975 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) # or use forcats::fct_lump(...
df %>% 
  mutate(name_lumped = fct_lump(name, w = Percent, prop = 0.01)) %>%
  group_by(name_lumped) %>%
  summarize(across(Year1:Percent, sum))

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  name_lumped Year1 Year2 Year3 Total Percent
  <fct>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 George         41    30    10    81   14.2 
2 Paul          230   100   150   480   84.4 
3 Other           3     3     2     8    1.41
```

Comment: Thank you!! I've never heard of fct_lump(), thanks for introducing me to it!